# How to change authentication mode and login using VS 2010 SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I created a database for a project I am working on and am using WCF to update a Datagridview in C#. My problem is that I originally selected Windows Authentication and I need to use SQL Server Authentication as I am using a school computer. Regardless of the mode I am new to logging into SQL Server in VS 2010 using **only** SQL Server Express.

My current connection string is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog= MyDatabase;uid=sa;pwd=sa;");
```

My error message is:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: ....
>   , error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

I really am clueless on this one and haven't found any help in the way of logging via SQL Server Authentication with SQL Server Express anywhere. Since this is just a exercise security really isn't a problem. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Drew

Comment: You need to change the configuration of SQL Server to Mixed Mode authentication.  Open up SQL server Management studio and right-click on the server instance.  Then select Security.  On the Left hand side you should see two radio buttons right at the top.  Select the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.  Then restart the instance of the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string you are missing the server name.  You need to add `Data Source=xxx` to your connection string. Also `uid` should be `User ID` and `pwd` should be `Password`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=Username;password=xxxxxxxx");
```

Where `Server` is the name of the computer hosting the SqlExpress.

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesn't solve the login problem.

Comment: Is the error still the same? Ensure that the server is available, and the port is not blocked by firewall or other application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the configuration of SQL Server to Mixed Mode authentication. Open up SQL server Management studio and right-click on the server instance. Then select Security. On the Left hand side you should see two radio buttons right at the top. Select the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. Then restart the instance of the server.

Also ensure that your sql server is allowing network connections.  This can be found under the Connections option.  It should be the 2nd to last checkbox.

Comment: I am not using Sql Server Management Studio